# Difference between re.search() and re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

The following code is very strange:

```
 >>> words = "4324324 blahblah"
 >>> print re.findall(r'(\s)\w+', words)
 [' ']
 >>> print re.search(r'(\s)\w+', words).group()
 blahblah
```

The `()` operator seems to behave poorly with findall. Why is this? I need it for a csv file.

Edit for clarity: I want to display `blahblah` using findall.

I discovered that `re.findall(r'\s(\w+)', words)` does what I want, but have no idea why findall treats groups in this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One character off:

```
>>> print re.search(r'(\s)\w+', words).groups()
(' ',)
>>> print re.search(r'(\s)\w+', words).group(1)
' '
```

`findall` returns a list of all groups captured. You're getting a space back because that's what you capture. Stop capturing, and it works fine:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'\s\w+', words)
[' blahblah']
```

Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

Comment: I think that should be `.group(1)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear, I wanted findall to behave like search, not the other way around. I needed to return 'blahblah'.

Comment: @CornSmith: Remove the grouping operator then

Comment: Thanks :) the grouping was the issue. Edit: OHHHH so THAT'S how findall behaves!

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer to keep the capturing groups in your regex, but you still want to find the entire contents of each match instead of the groups, you can use the following:

```
[m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(\s)\w+', words)]
```

For example:

```
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(\s)\w+', '4324324 blahblah')]
[' blahblah']
```