# Python regex: Difference between (.+) and (.+?)

Tags: python, regex, urllib

I am new to regex and Python's urllib. I went through an online tutorial on web scraping and it had the following code. After studying up on regular expressions, it seemed to me that I could use (.+) instead of the (.+?) in my regex, but whoa was I wrong. I ended up printing way more html code than I wanted. I thought I was getting the hang of regex, but now I am confused. Please explain to me the difference between these two expressions and why it is grabbing so much html. Thanks!

ps. this is a starbucks stock quote scraper.

```
import urllib
import re

url = urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SBUX")
htmltext = url.read()
regex = re.compile('<span id="yfs_l84_sbux">(.+?)</span>')
found = re.findall(regex, htmltext)
```

print found

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between .\*? and .\* for regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)

Comment: FYI, [it is a bad idea to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: Okay calm down bud, I'm just using this as a learning tool. I am new regex and urllib and I thought this would be a nice sandbox exercise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.+` is greedy -- it matches until it can't match any more and gives back only as much as needed.

`.+?` is not -- it stops at the first opportunity.

Examples:

Assume you have this HTML:

```
<span id="yfs_l84_sbux">foo bar</span><span id="yfs_l84_sbux2">foo bar</span>
```

This regex matches the whole thing:

```
<span id="yfs_l84_sbux">(.+)<\/span>
```

It goes all the way to the end, then "gives back" one `</span>`, but the rest of the regex matches that last `</span>`, so the complete regex matches the entire HTML chunk.

But this regex stops at the first `</span>`:

```
<span id="yfs_l84_sbux">(.+?)<\/span>
```

Comment: You are awesome! Easy to understand explanation. Maybe you could explain this to me as well. Why, in my case, does re.search return a strange looking string, while re.findall gives me that data I am actually wanting?

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13887574/2057919) helpful. `findall` returns a list of the groups captured, while `search` returns everything that matched. In your case, that includes the HTML tags. I'm a bit of a beginner in Python, but I believe you will get the same result from both methods if you remove the parentheses from the regex.

Answer (score 3):

`?` is a non-greedy modifier. `*` by default is a greedy repetition operator - it will gobble up everything it can; when modified by `?` it becomes non-greedy and will eat up only as much as will satisfy it.

Thus for

```
<span id="yfs_l84_sbux">want</span>text<span id="somethingelse">dontwant</span>
```

`.*?</span>` will eat up `want`, then hit `</span>` - and this satisfies the regexp with minimal repetitions of `.`, resulting in `<span id="yfs_l84_sbux">want</span>` being the match. However, `.*` will try to see if it can eat more - it will go and find the other `</span>`, with `.*?` matching `want</span>text<span id="somethingelse">dontwant`, resulting in what you got - much more than you wanted.

Comment: `*`? The OP actually uses `+`.

Comment: Doh. Well, same reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

`(.+)` is greedy. It takes what it can and gives back when needed.

`(.+?)` is ungreedy. It takes as few as possible.

See:

```
delegate

[delegate] /^(.+)e/
[de]legate /^(.+?)e/
```

Also, comparing the "Regex debugger log" [here](http://regex101.com/r/iB5dI0/1) and [here](http://regex101.com/r/iB5dI0/2) will show you what the ungreedy modifier does more effectively.